# StanfordNLP custom relation extraction

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to make a custom relation extractor using Stanford NLP Core. I downloaded their file kill.corp. I trained this file.

Look at the example: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml

Now, when I use the following command to identify the kill relation by loading my model (kill model).

`java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -sup.relation.model=tmp/roth_relation_model_pipeline.ser -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref,relation`

Because I did not have input file the terminal allows me to write a sentence - "Joe killed Jack" and it doesn't identify any relations. However, when I write a sentence with Live_In already built in StanfordNLP "Julia lives in California" it works fine.

Extracted the following MachineReading relation mentions:

> RelationMention [type=Located_In, start=0, end=4, {Located_In, 0.37758087211058006; _NR, 0.2433177585101524; OrgBased_In, 0.15485273181687478; Live_In, 0.14393618927198826; Work_For, 0.08031244829040446}
>       EntityMention [type=PEOPLE, objectId=EntityMention-3, hstart=0, hend=1, estart=0, eend=1, headPosition=0, value="Julia", corefID=-1]
>       EntityMention [type=O, objectId=EntityMention-4, hstart=3, hend=4, estart=3, eend=4, headPosition=3, value="California", corefID=-1]

How can I add kill as a relation and get my custom relation model to identify it?

Comment: I see an unpaired [ - could that be an issue?

Comment: I think unpaired is the problem. So, plz how can I fix this.